# how to auto delete file in drive d:if creation time > 30 days vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program that auto delete file in drive d: if the file is more than 30 days, I made a search and I found out I can compare the creationtime of the files and the datenow, I tried code below but it didn't work.

My file in drive d is march 7 2018 and I change my computer date to april 10 2018 so that it will be more than 30 days but it didn't work.

I have 2 button in my form the first one is to select the path which folder to delete. And the second button is to set that after 30 days it will automatic delete data.

My code below please help correct where I am wrong. I am new in vb.net .

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class DeleteByDay

    Private Sub btnDeleteDay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteDay.Click
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            txtPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSet_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSet.Click
       Dim eachFileInMydirectory As New DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text)
       Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo

       Try
           For Each fileName In eachFileInMydirectory.GetFiles
               If fileName.Extension.Equals("*.spi") AndAlso
                  (Now - fileName.CreationTime).Days > 30 Then

                   fileName.Delete()
               End If
           Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No Files older than 90 days exists be deleted " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: what is `Now` in your code? It's not defined in your snippet. Is it a DateTime? You probably want to be using DateTime.Compare (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an accurate comparison of your date rather than simple subtraction.

Comment: Instead of .Equals("*.spi") Try (".spi") Just get rid of the * This isn't a wide card search Extension returns the the extension with the dot.

Comment: @Mary still not deleting. i remove * already.

Comment: @ADyson `Now` refers to `DateTime.Now` in a default WinForms-project in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Bonito "it didn't work" does not tell us enough: in what way did it not work? Did you get an error message that you can copy into the question?

Comment: @Andrew Morton ,there was no error message, it just didn't execute the way i want to be. it didn't delete the data in the path i want to delete after 30 days.

Comment: So are you saying it calculates the date incorrectly? Like I said above, use DateTime.Compare to properly calculate the difference between your dates. You should be able to use your debugger to set breakpoints, so you can check the value of Days being returned, and see whether your code is entering the `If` block or not. That way you'll be able to give a more accurate description that simply "it didn't do what I wanted".

Comment: @ADyson can you show me how to compare the date from my computer to the date of all my files in drive d ? and if the date in my files is less than 30 days already then it will be deleted. is that possible? please show me . thanks.

Comment: Apologies, for this you should be using DateTime.DateDiff, not Compare. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127413(v=vs.110).aspx . There's lots of explanation in that link, and even an example of using it to output the number of days between two dates.

Comment: You should not change the date and time on your computer like that - other things may get broken. All you need to do, for testing purposes, is use `New DateTime(2100, 1, 1)` instead of `Now` to guarantee that more than 30 days have passed.

Comment: @ADyson Subtracting one DateTime from another is defined to give a TimeSpan, so there should be no need to use the less-intuitive DateDiff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fileName seems to only have the file name. You need the full path to Delete.

```
Dim eachFileInMydirectory As New DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFolder")
Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo

For Each fileName In eachFileInMydirectory.GetFiles
    If fileName.Extension.Equals(".txt") AndAlso (Now - fileName.CreationTime).Days > 8 Then
        Dim fullPath As String = Path.Combine("C:\MyFolder", fileName.ToString)
        File.Delete(fullPath)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to programming, what about my code inside try catch ? what should i put?

Comment: Comment ou fileName.Delete and add my code right below it

Comment: i got an error Delete is not a member of string. in fullPath.Delete()

Comment: One more time, File.Delete(fullPath)  Sorry, I am going back and forth to C# and some IO code there. It's the same but I keep messing it up.

Comment: NO need to sorry, your amazing now there is no error message but still didn't delete the data i already change the date in my computer more than 60days then when i click button still not delete.

Comment: Let's see if any files are meeting your criteria. Put Debug.Print(fullPath) right above the .Delete. This will show up in the Immediate window after you run it. Debug menu > Windows >Immediate

Comment: it shows like this.                                                          
 A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DeletebyDate.My.MyApplication.New'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DeletebyDate.My.MyApplication.__ENCAddToList'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Activator.CreateInstance<DeletebyDate.My.MyApplication>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DeletebyDate.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainFor

Comment: My code is deleting. I had to change the criteria a bit to match what was on my drive. I will add it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: your codes work perfect in deleting .txt but not work with .spi ?  i also try " * " but not work.

Comment: i also want the user to choose which path or folder to delete like my code above. i tried it but didn't work .

Comment: @AndrewMorton I believe that fileName is type FileInfo.

Comment: @Mary Oops! Yes. Correction: `fileName` is of type FileInfo, which has a Delete method. There is no need to re-make the full filename. Also, a FileInfo has a FullName property, which is the filename with the path.

Comment: @Mary ok let me try again tomorrow the txtpath .what about the ".spi" any comment?  I think it only work with .txt.

Comment: @Mary now it works thank you very much  for your code very short and easy to analyze for beginners like me.... i removed the if filename.extension.equal".txt" so that it will delete all files inside the folder not only .txt. and my txtPath.text yeah it works fine now....

Comment: @Mary i have one more question . how can i keep my button click ? i mean it should be automatic delete the files older than 30 days. i tried to put your code in a checkbox if checkbox is true then execute our code but i think it is not executing. please suggest.

Comment: So glad it is working! I am guessing you put the code in the check_changed event. Putting myself in the users shoes, I would rather have the code in a button. When I check a check box, I am selecting an option, not doing the deed. Clicking a button means something is going to happen. Just my perception.

Comment: @Mary I got it now.. i just use a timer to call the button to execute the delete . i will post my answer in summary in case someone will do same program i did. thanks a lot . your a life saver..

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work, so there must be something else going wrong.

I assume there is a reason for "btnDeleteDay" to select the directory and "btnSet" to do the delete, but the names don't seem to match their functions.

The premise that an exception will be thrown if there are no files to delete is wrong - you may consider it an error, but there is nothing wrong as far as the code goes.

You can add more checks to the code so that it tells you if there was a reason that no files were deleted. Also, you can filter which files are retrieved by DirectotyInfo.GetFiles, so there will be no need to check for the extension.

Don't worry about using extra variables to make the code look really simple: simple code is usually easy to maintain.

I came up with the following code based on what you showed, and there's a small method to create some files for testing:

```
Private Sub btnSelectDirectory_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelectDirectory.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "C:\temp" ' for testing

    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        txtPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteOldFiles_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteOldFiles.Click
    Dim dir = txtPath.Text

    Dim directoryToProcess As New DirectoryInfo(dir)
    Dim fileExtension = ".spi"

    Dim filesToProcess = directoryToProcess.GetFiles("*" & fileExtension)
    Dim nFilesDeleted = 0

    If filesToProcess.Count > 0 Then
        For Each fileName As IO.FileInfo In filesToProcess
            Dim fileAge = DateTime.Now - fileName.CreationTime

            If fileAge > TimeSpan.FromDays(30) Then
                Try
                    fileName.Delete()
                    nFilesDeleted += 1
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to delete file." & vbCrLf & ex.Message, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                End Try
            End If

        Next

        If nFilesDeleted = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format( "No {0} file older than 90 days exists be deleted.",fileExtension))
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"There are no {0} files in directory {1}.", fileExtension, dir))

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub bnMakeSampleFiles_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnMakeSampleFiles.Click
    ' sub to create test data
    Dim dest = "C:\temp"

    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim fName = Path.Combine(dest, i.ToString() & ".spi")
        File.WriteAllText(fName, i.ToString())
        Dim fi = New FileInfo(fName)
        fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(25 + i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried your code and got an error in $ sign. i tried to delete it and run the program it calls the last message box no file extension in directory but i have .spi .sorry im a beginners.

Comment: The $ indicates an interpolated string but you need a more recent version of VB to use it.     Replace with String.Format 
    MessageBox.Show($"There are no {fileExtension} files in directory {dir}.") becomes    String.Format("There are no {0} files in directory {1}.", fielExtension, dir)

Comment: @Mary Thank you for pointing that out - I'll update the answer.